# Graph doubts in OCaml and functions related with graphs

Tags: graph, ocaml

I have this code here:

```
type ('state,'letter) automaton = {
  initial    : 'state ;
  final      : 'state -> bool ;
  transition : 'letter -> 'state -> 'state ;
}   

let example_graph =
{ 
nodes = ['a'; 'c'; 'd'; 'f'; 'g'; 'h'; 'k'];
edges = ['h', 'g';  'k', 'f';  'f', 'b';  'f', 'c';  'c', 'b']

}
```

It is the default example given by OCaml web site about graths.

Well my question here is, how do I work with Graphs in `OCaml`? I mean with `Lists` we have a large function page that helps us working with it but I have not found anything about predefined functions with graphs.

I have a complex work to do with graphs, to be more precise, I need to build a `automaton` with `OCaml`, but first I would like to understand how  can I do simple thinks such as getting `nodes` from a graph, how can I turn my nodes and edges input values, or how can I do tests with a graph like this one I have here, for example how can I travel between the nodes...(well every simple moves you can remember or any place I can get more informed will help)

Basically I want to know if there is any place in the web where I can get better information about graphs in OCaml or functions, and if you guys can give me a hand to!

Thanks

PS: I have already done my search and found nothing really useful (only to much complex code for a beginner like me)

Comment: Maybe this would be a good starting point: http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/index.en.html

Comment: This will help me for sure! Thanks. I hope I can understand it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think ocamlgraph is a bit complex for a new OCaml programmer (but later it would be a great idea to use it).

From what I understand, you want to handle in an understandable way, nodes and edges.

To start, I would give you the advice of testing the [Map module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.Make.html) (with it's [tutorial](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/map.html)) because it's a fast and simple way of doing it (I implemented the [Glushkov's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glushkov's_construction_algorithm) with this module and it works really well).

To give you a small insight :

```
type ('state,'letter) automaton = {
  initial    : 'state ;
  final      : 'state -> bool ;
  transition : 'letter -> 'state -> 'state ;
}
```

This is how you saw an automaton until now.

```
type ('state,'letter) automaton = {
  initial    : 'state ;
  final      : 'state -> bool ;
  transition : ('letter, 'state) list Map.Make('state);
}
```

This is how I see it (it's not a correct implementation since `'state` is not an obvious ordered type but the idea is here). You can Map any state to a list (and maybe if you understand how to create a new Map you will use [Set](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.S.html) instead of list) of states.

Try to implement it on your own, it can be really useful and you can learn a lot about it.

Answer (score 1):

OCaml has an excellent support for graphs, thanks to [OCamlgraph](http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/index.en.html) library. It is well documented, and very powerful, but it relies on functors a lot, and they usually confuse OCaml newbies. So you might also consider to try another [graph library](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/lib/graphlib/graphlib.mli) that we started for the purpose of program analysis. It is not released to the official opam repository, but you can always get the latest alpha version from our own repository:

```
opam repository add git://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/opam-repository.git
opam install graphlib
```

P.S. Graphlib is not a substitution for OCamlgraph, it plays with it very well. It just have a little bit different focus. OCamlGraph focuses more on generic algorithms that will work on any graph representation, when graphlib 
focuses more on a graph data structure. So it is easier to use, but harder to extend.